# internet access for system over multiple hops of ipsec using GRE and OSPF

Tags: linux, ipsec, gre, ospf, bird

I have the following setup:
linux client @ 172.16.10.68

linux gateway @ 172.16.10.69, ipsec tunnel to aws box #1, gre tunnel 
10.254.0.0/30

aws box #1, ipsec tunnel from linux gw, ipsec tunnel to aws box #2, gre tunnel 1 10.254.0.0/30 and second gre tunnel 10.254.0.4/30

aws box #2, ipsec tunnel from aws box #1, ipsec tunnel to aws box #3, gre tunnel 1 10.254.0.4/30 and second gre tunnel 10.254.0.8/30

I have bird running OSPF on the linux gateway, aws 1, aws 2, and aws 3. ipsec tunnel from aws box #2, gre tunnel1 10.254.0.8/30.

example bird conf:
protocol ospf MyOSPF {
        tick 2;
        area 0.0.0.0 {
                stub no;
                networks {
                        172.16.29.244/32;
                        10.254.0.4/30;
                        10.254.0.8/30;
                        10.254.0.0/30;
                        172.16.10.0/24;
                };
                default cost 100;
                stubnet 172.16.29.244/32 {
                        cost 100;
                };
                interface "tun1";
        };
}

What I'm trying to accomplish is to provide internet access to the the linux client from aws box #3 over multiple hops. With the current configuration I can ping GRE tunnel IPs just fine, but none of the ethernet interfaces on the AWS boxes. I am open to suggestions and recommendations.